# How do I specify a class label for each value when I want to store recall_score in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, precision-recall

In a multi-class classification problem (including 15 classes), I want to store recall_scores (or precision_score).

How can I store recall_scores  in a dictionary to access the value of each class?

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=30)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = data
    
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

labels = list(set(y_pred))

recall_scores = sklearn.metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred, average=None, labels=labels, zero_division=1)
```

Although I have set the labels attribute, I can not recognize the value of each class.

This is what I got:

```
[50.0, 100.0, 75.0, 75.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 75.0, 75.0, 75.0, 100.0, 100.0, 75.0, 100.0]
```

But this is what I want:

```
{'A': 50.0, 'B': 100.0, 'C': 75.0, 'D': 75.0, 'E': 100.0, 
 'F': 100.0, 'G': 100.0, 'H': 100.0, 'I': 75.0, 'J': 75.0, 
 'K': 75.0, 'L': 100.0, 'M': 100.0, 'N': 75.0, 'O': 100.0}
```

Comment: I think this should do `dict(zip(labels, recall_scores))`

Comment: @DaveIdito Actually I do not want to do it manually. I want this to happen when the values ​​are stored. How to use the "labels" attribute in recall_score function?
I really do not understand how the presence or absence of the labels attribute in this function helps.

Comment: You will have to do manually, well, unless if you write your own implementation, and you don't need to because you can interpret the result without any ambiguity. `labels` would be needed 1. for non-binary classifications 2. to get the score per label/class.